# Using iptables TPROXY to listen on all ports with outgoing traffic

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

My issue is that I can't establish an outgoing connection.

I followed this [blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-we-built-spectrum/) to use TPROXY to redirect any TCP connection to a single listener:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port=1234 --on-ip=127.0.0.1
```

I replaces the `-d 192.0.2.0/24` with `-i eth0` but from my understanding this shouldn't make a difference from the problem I'm facing.

I'm running a listener with `IP_TRANSPARENT` and I get all connections as expected.

Occasionally I want to establish outgoing TCP connections and if I read it correctly, the SYN packets go out as expected but any response get picked up by the TPROXY rule and are dropped.

I assume there is a possible solution using routing?

As suggested I tried adding a route for outgoing connection like this:

```
echo "10 tproxy" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 10.x.x.81 table tproxy
ip route add default via 10.x.x.80 dev ens2 table tproxy
```

```
# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from 10.x.x.81 lookup tproxy
...
# ip route show table tproxy
default via 10.64.70.80 dev ens2
```

And update the iptables rule to:

```
-A PREROUTING ! -s 10.x.x.81/32 -i ens2 -p tcp -m tcp ! --dport 22 -j TPROXY --on-port 5000 --on-ip 127.0.0.1
```

Still with the same issue:

```
11:42:28.172268 IP hostname.46324 > remote.https: Flags [S], seq 2783956497, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1288228251 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:42:28.173479 IP remote.https > hostname.46324: Flags [S.], seq 573845087, ack 2783956498, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3249746343 ecr 1288227230,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:42:29.202975 IP remote.https > hostname.46324: Flags [S.], seq 573845087, ack 2783956498, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3249747372 ecr 1288227230,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:42:29.620887 IP hostname.46334 > remote.https: Flags [S], seq 1774017241, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1288229700 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:42:29.621686 IP remote.https > hostname.46334: Flags [S.], seq 1078655880, ack 1774017242, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3249747791 ecr 1288229700,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because `TPROXY` rule is intercepting all incoming traffic and redirecting it to the listener

You could allow outgoing connections is to use policy routing to route the outgoing traffic around the `TPROXY` rule

Here is how: first we create a new routing table `echo "10 tproxy" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables` then we add new routing rule `ip rule add from <your_ip_address> table tproxy` then we add a new defaut route `ip route add default via <your_default_gateway> dev eth0 table tproxy` finaly we modify TPROXY rule to only match traffic that is not originating from our IP address

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING ! -s <your_ip_address> -i eth0 -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port=1234 --on-ip=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Here is my default route:

`default via 10.x.x.80 dev ens2 proto dhcp src 10.x.x.81 metric 100`

New route as per your suggestion:
`ip route show table tproxy`

`default via 10.x.x.80 dev ens2`

Here is the iptables rule:

`TPROXY     tcp  -- !<hostname>              anywhere             tcp dpt:!ssh TPROXY redirect 127.0.0.1:5000`